# GDAL Calc Set Specific Values to Another Number

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, raster-calculator, gdal-calc

I have a GeoTiff raster with a format of Float32 and values 0.00 to 5.00. I am attempting to change all raster cells with a value **below 0.10** to **0.10**, and leave all other cells in the raster dataset unchanged.

Using some of the basic code examples provided on the GDAL Man pages, the initial snippet of code I used is as follows:

```
--calc="A*(A<0.10)"
```

The code executes successfully, however this sets all values below 0.10 to zero. What alteration to the formula needs to be made in order to meet the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the expression you have, `A*(A<0.10)`

`(A<0.10)` evaluates to a boolean, either `True` or `False`

If a boolean is used in place of a numeric value, `True` is equivalent to `1` while `False` is equivalent to `0`

So when A is less than 0.1, we'd expect those values to be multiplied by 1 and remain, while values greater than that would be multiplied by 0.  Not what we want.

Instead try doing `(A*(A>=0.1))+(0.1*(A<0.1))`.  This should maintain the value (multiply by 1) if it's over 0.1, otherwise set it to zero.  Then we add 0.1 to it if it's under 0.1, otherwise add 0.